# Understanding grid and bloc in cp.RawKernel

Tags: cupy

The example shown in https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/cupy/latest/cupy.pdf at page 11 regarding use of cp.RawKernel is not clear to me in terms of usage of grid, block because the matrixes are square.

I tried to change the shape of the matrixes and try to play with grid and block.
Is not clear to me why to get correct results I have to set grid 8 and block 8
like 
multiply((8, ), (8, ), (p, q, z))  # grid, block and arguments

```
import cupy as cp #Importing CuPy

#Defining the CUDA kernel
multiply = cp.RawKernel(r'''
extern "C" __global__
void multiply(const int* p, const int* q, int* z) {
    int tid = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    z[tid] = p[tid] + q[tid];
 }
''', 'multiply')

#First two arrays are set as 0,1,2,3....upto 300
p = cp.arange(30, dtype=cp.int).reshape(6,5)
q = cp.arange(30, dtype=cp.int).reshape(6,5)

#Setting a new array with zeros to pass to kernel for computation
z = cp.zeros((6,5), dtype=cp.int)
#Invoking the kernel with a grid of 250 blocks, each consisting of 1024 threads
multiply((6, ), (5, ), (p, q, z))  # grid, block and arguments

#Displaying the output computed on the kernel
print(z)
```

I was expecting to retrieve correct results setting like in code above 
multiply((6, ), (5, ), (p, q, z))  # grid, block and arguments

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You also changed the data types from the example you referenced, and you did it incorrectly.

If you specify the correct cupy data type (`cp.int32`) to match the raw kernel data type you have chosen (`int`) then your code works correctly for me, as is:

```
$ cat t7.py
import cupy as cp #Importing CuPy

#Defining the CUDA kernel
multiply = cp.RawKernel(r'''
extern "C" __global__
void multiply(const int* p, const int* q, int* z) {
    int tid = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    z[tid] = p[tid] + q[tid];
 }
''', 'multiply')

#First two arrays are set as 0,1,2,3....upto 300
p = cp.arange(30, dtype=cp.int32).reshape(6,5)
q = cp.arange(30, dtype=cp.int32).reshape(6,5)

#Setting a new array with zeros to pass to kernel for computation
z = cp.zeros((6,5), dtype=cp.int32)
#Invoking the kernel with a grid of 250 blocks, each consisting of 1024 threads
multiply((6, ), (5, ), (p, q, z))  # grid, block and arguments

#Displaying the output computed on the kernel
print(z)
$ python t7.py
[[ 0  2  4  6  8]
 [10 12 14 16 18]
 [20 22 24 26 28]
 [30 32 34 36 38]
 [40 42 44 46 48]
 [50 52 54 56 58]]
$
```